# Is it possible to compose two sealed classes?

Tags: kotlin, sealed-class

Image that I have two distinct Kotlin sealed classes.

```
sealed class Fruit {
  object Apple : Fruit()
  object Orange : Fruit()
  object Banana : Fruit()
}

sealed class Vegetables {
  object Broccoli : Vegetable()
  object Carrot : Vegetable()
  object Spinach : Vegetable()
}
```

Is it possible to define a type that is encompasses Fruits and Vegetables? Something like `Produce = Fruit | Vegetable`

So that you could write something like

```
fun lookAtProduce(produce: Produce) {
  when (produce) {
    is Carrot -> {
      return "Orange"
    }
    is Apple -> {
      return "Red"
    }
    ....
  }
}

fun putItInSalad(vegetable: Vegetable) {
  when (vegetable) {
    is Spinach -> {
      return true
    }
    is Carrot -> {
      return false
    }
    .....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking about a [union type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type).  There have been [long discussions](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/union-types/77/3) about adding one to Kotlin, but it doesn't look likely to happen soon.

Meanwhile, you can of course have an explicit parent class:

```
sealed class Produce
```

The rest then works pretty much as you'd expect:

```
sealed class Fruit : Produce() {
    object Apple : Fruit()
    object Orange : Fruit()
    object Banana : Fruit()
}

sealed class Vegetable : Produce() {
    object Broccoli : Vegetable()
    object Carrot : Vegetable()
    object Spinach : Vegetable()
}

fun lookAtProduce(produce: Produce) =
    when (produce) {
        is Vegetable.Carrot ->  "Orange"
        is Fruit.Apple ->  "Red"
        else -> TODO()
    }
}

fun putItInSalad(vegetable: Vegetable) =
    when (vegetable) {
        is Vegetable.Spinach -> true
        is Vegetable.Carrot -> false
        else -> TODO()
    }
}
```

(You have to qualify `Carrot` etc. unless you add static imports for them.)

(The nice thing about [`TODO()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html) is that it works both as documentation and as a way to get incomplete code to compile!)

Of course, this requires you to have access to both the types you want to combine, so you can add the common parent class.  If you can't do that, a more long-winded option would be to use an `Either` class (see e.g. [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/implementing-kotlin-either/8730)).  That would need the produce to be explicitly wrapped and unwrapped, but is probably the nearest you can get in that case.

Comment: You're right that this solves the problem I posed in the question, sadly it doesn't solve my real life problem (I oversimplified for the purposes of posing the question quickly)

What I'm really interested in in having multiple variants of a base sealed class. Union types is absolutely what I want.

I think that I could accomplish this by extending the base sealed class, but it isn't allowed in the version of Kotlin I'm using because they are not all defined in the same file. My understanding is that in newer versions it could be done within a package.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a union type, but you can always emulate it with another sealed type.

```
sealed class Produce {
  class FruitProduce(val fruit: Fruit): Produce()
  class VegetableProduce(val vegetable: Vegetable): Produce()
}
```

...and write

```
fun color(produce: Produce): String {
  return when (produce) {
    is Fruit -> when (produce.fruit) {
      is Orange -> "Orange"
      ...
    }
    is Vegetable -> when (produce.vegetable) {
      is Broccoli -> "Green"
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing better than this is possible today: you will need to wrap your `fruit` and `vegetable` objects in `FruitProduce` and `VegetableProduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a super class:

```
sealed class Produce
sealed class Fruit : Produce()
sealed class Vegetable : Produce()
```